# Selecting Multiple div Nodes with different class with xpath in C#

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to select div nodes with different class with xpath. what should I do?
I wrote this code, But it returns error.

```
HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();
string SearchResults = "http://www.ask.com/web?q=" + query.querytxt;
var hd = w.Load(SearchResults);
var titles = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class='web-result ur tsrc')] && //div[contains(@class='web-result ur tsrc_Wiki-SA '] && //div[contains(@class='web-result ur tsrc_tube youtube-result ']");
```

I need these divs

```
//div[contains(@class='web-result ur tsrc')]
//div[contains(@class='web-result ur tsrc_Wiki-SA ')]
//div[contains(@class='web-result ur tsrc_tube youtube-result ']
```

this is the error:

> Function 'contains' in '//div[contains(@class='web-result ur tsrc')]
>   && //div[contains(@class='web-result ur tsrc_Wiki-SA '] &&
>   //div[contains(@class='web-result ur tsrc_tube youtube-result ']' has
>   an invalid number of arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `xpath` [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function works with `,` to compare value instead of `=`. So try as below with correct `xpath` :-

```
//div[contains(@class, 'web-result ur tsrc')]
//div[contains(@class, 'web-result ur tsrc_Wiki-SA ')]
//div[contains(@class, 'web-result ur tsrc_tube youtube-result ')]
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: I've seen many examples on Stackoverflow that cites the contains() function. Most of them tell you to use the Contains() multiple times but I couldn't get any of them to work. Yours is the first that calls it only once AND it actually works! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

to select all div(s) (nodes) with different class names, search directly for class names.

you can do this as following:

```
hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("@class='web-result ur tsrc' or @class='web-result ur tsrc_Wiki-SA' or @class='web-result ur tsrc_tube youtube-result ']");
```